# can't return a variable outside the function

Tags: python, arguments

I am trying to return the output from a function and trying to do a function call in  a`for` loop and printing the output in same loop. But it is not working:

```
pagination_urls = ["http://google.com"]

def oss(url):
    data = url
    return data


for url in pagination_urls:
    oss(url)
    spider = data
    print spider
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongo.py", line 10, in <module>
    spider = data
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

How to make this program work?

Comment: `spider = oss(url)`? `data= oss(url); spider = data`? Python isn't (totally) magic, you need to tell it what you mean! Perhaps you should read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the output of oss() to any variable. Try this:

```
pagination_urls = ["http://google.com"]

def oss(url):
    data = url
    return data


for url in pagination_urls:
    data = oss(url)
    spider = data
    print spider
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the returned value

```
for url in pagination_urls:
    spider = oss(url)
    print spider
```

This will take the returned value `data` from the `oss` function, and assign it to your `spider` variable

Answer (score 0):

Local variables in one function do not magically appear outside of that function. `return` returns the *value*, not the name of the variable. Instead, explicitly assign the return value:

```
for url in pagination_urls:
    spider = oss(url)
    print spider
```

Here the return value of `oss()` (whatever object the `return` statement produced in `oss`) is assigned to the `spider` variable.